# my searchbar is working with done button how should it call the same method with search button of keybaord :iphone

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar, keyboard-events

In my application user input some text in searchbar and application genrate RSS feed agiant this text when done button is pressed.
I want that the same action is performed when the user click on search button of keyboard.

Any Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a delegate on your UISearchBar and implement the delegate method

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```